# Java 8 stream peek and limit interaction

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why this code in java 8:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .peek(System.out::print)
        .limit(3)
        .count();
```

outputs:

```
012
```

I'd expect it to output `0123456789`, because peek preceeds limit.

It seems to me even more peculiar because of the fact that this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .peek(System.out::print)
        .map(x -> x * 2)
        .count();
```

outputs `0123456789` as expected (not `02481012141618`).

P.S.: `.count()` here is used just to consume stream, it can be replaced with anything else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

`limit()` is a `short-circuiting stateful intermediate operation.`

`map()` is an `intermediate operation`

Again from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) what that essentially means is that `limit()` will return a stream  with `x` values from the stream it received.

> An intermediate operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may produce a finite stream as a result.

Answer (score 15):

The most important thing to know about streams are that they do not contain elements themselves (like collections) but are working like a pipe whose values are *lazily* evaluated. That means that the statements that build up a stream - including mapping, filtering, or whatever - are not evaluated until the terminal operation runs.

In your first example, the stream tries to count from 0 to 9, one at each time doing the following:

1. print out the value
2. check whether 3 values are passed (if yes, terminate)

So you really get the output `012`.

In your second example, the stream again counts from 0 to 9, one at each time doing the following:

1. print out the value
2. maping x to x*2, thus forwarding the double of the value to the next step

As you can see the output comes before the mapping and thus you get the result `0123456789`. Try to switch the `peek` and the `map` calls. Then you will get your expected output.

Answer (score 5):

`Stream`s are defined to do lazy processing. So in order to complete your `count()` operation it doesn’t need to look at the other items. Otherwise, it would be broken, as `limit(…)` is defined to be a proper way of processing infinite streams in a finite time (by not processing more than `limit` items).

In principle, it would be possible to complete your request without ever looking at the `int` values at all, as the operation chain `limit(3).count()` doesn’t need any processing of the previous operations (other than verifying whether the stream has at least `3` items).

Comment: It is true that `count` wouldn't need to process the values in this scenario, but for example if the values come from a file stream it's different. The Stream interface must have a consistent behaviour; the last paragraph is therefore confusing/distracting.

Comment: @Jimmy T.: there is no guaranty that a `Stream` will process an item in its contract, so relying on a file pointer to be advanced to a certain position when your terminal operation is `count()` would be a bug on your side. In fact, short-circuiting `count()` operations, is on the list of planed improvements for Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

Streams use lazy evaluation, the intermediate operations, i.e. *peek()* are not executed till the terminal operation runs.
For instances, the following code will just print **1** .In fact, as soon as the first element of the stream,1, will reach the terminal operation, *findAny()*, the stream execution will be ended.

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3)
            .stream()
            .peek(System.out::print)
            .filter((n)->n<3)
            .findAny();
```

Viceversa, in the following example, will be printed **123**. In fact the terminal operation, *noneMatch()*, needs to evaluate all the elements of the stream in order to make sure there is no match with its Predicate: *n>4*

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
            .stream()
            .peek(System.out::print)
            .noneMatch(n -> n > 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers struggling to understand how the `count` method doesn't execute the `peek` method before it, I thought I add this additional note:

As per Java 9, the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) for the `count` method states that:

> An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline
> (either sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the
> count directly from the stream source.

This means terminating the stream with `count` is no longer enough to ensure the execution of all previous steps, such as `peek`.